# Incorporating gyroscope data information in accelerator data in iPhone

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, sensor-data

I am performing Human Action Recognition based on IPhone sensor data. One approach that worked excellently was plotting this data and using image-based models.

Currently, I am training my models on plots of only accelerometer data. However, I'd like to include the gyro data as well since the way the phone is held could vary from user to user and the gyro data would capture these differences.

Based on the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/getting_raw_gyroscope_events), this gyro data represents the values in radiants. Hence I was thinking to use it to normalize the accelerometer data by swapping the axes of the acc readings if the gyro reading passes a certain threshold.

So, if the phone is initially on the default position that is shown in the above-linked docs for the `x-y-z axes` (i.e. vertical position), and then it changes by 90 degrees downwards and ends up in a horizontal position I also need to correspondingly change the axes of the accelerometer readings. This means that the previous `y-axis` becomes the new `z-axis` and vice-versa, with the `x-axis` remaining unchanged.

My question here is whether this method is sound. Based on my understanding, the axes of the accelerometer would be changing every 90 degrees, which is equal to `1.5708` gradients. So if the gyro data for a particular reading exceeds this threshold of `+1.5708`, then I swap the values for the axes of the corresponding acceleration row of data as described above. If it changes by `2 * +1.5708`, then I swap them again accordingly.

Otherwise, if you have other suggestions for making use of the gyro data to normalize the accelerometer data, or fuse them together, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to do, but the first thing that came to my mind was to use the attitude angles in a coordinate transformation.

Unfortunately, it is probably not as simple as you describe it, as is nicely presented in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170010/iphone-understanding-iphone-rotation).

What you can do is to transform your accelerations from its body-fixed coordinate system into a reference frame. If you don't do that, your accelerations are changing with the attitude of your device. If the device is just standing on it's long side on the table (as illustrated in the link of yours), you will see a gravity vector of $a = \begin{pmatrix} -g \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. If you lay the device on its back on the table, it will show $a = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -g \end{pmatrix}$.

If you want to know the accelerations relative to a reference frame, e.g. the table, you can use the rotation described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128906/euler-angles-to-rotation-matrix-manual-transformation-for-ios-devices). This can be useful if you want to know how the device is being moved through your room intependently of how it is held.

By the way, these transformations (rotation matrices) are apparently supported on your iOS and described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmattitude#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CMAttitude).

Comment: Updated the question a little bit to try to make it clearer. 

I am not sure how to use the information given in the link.


Essentially what I need to do is kind of fuse the accelerometer and gyroscope values and make an image plot out of them. If I just use acc for my model, I am going to get different results if a user holds the phone differently in this hand, right (but these changes will be reflected in the gyro data)?

Comment: I edited the answer and it is hopefully a bit more clear now...

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [augmenting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_augmentation) your accelerometer data by applying rotations so that the trained classifier is robust against changes in sensor orientation?

This approach has been successfully tried in similar tasks, e.g. [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.00527.pdf)

> *One factor that can introduce label-invariant variability of wearable sensor data are differences in sensor placement between participants. For example, an upside-down placement of the sensor can
> invert the sign of the sensor readings without changing the labels.
> Therefore, augmentation by applying arbitrary rotations (Rot) to
> the existing data can be used as a way of simulating different sensor
> placements.
> (...)
> The best performance among the single data augmentation methods
> is achieved by rotation*

or [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/13/5/845/pdf)

> *In the gravity rotation step, we used the fact that the measured gravitational acceleration could be slightly different for each trial, even for the same activity. Therefore, ag was
> slightly rotated about the forward component of qh
> to generate new data. In internal test,
> rotation ranges within $[−10^\circ, 10^\circ]$ generally improved the inference performance of the
> neural network.*

Otherwise, note that the orientation of the (accelerometer) sensor has a continuous spectrum (unless you're only accounting for the basic 90-degree rotations) which would require you to construct a rotation matrix out of your gyroscope readings to preprocess your accelerometer readings.